# Git post-receive hook leaves files to be committed

Tags: git, githooks

Three places git is installed:  Local, Bare, and Development.

I push from Local to Bare, post-receive hook pushes my dev branch from Bare to Development.  The commits appear in the git log just fine, however, if Development is currently on the branch it's receiving, I get a modified list of files staged and ready to commit.

The thing is the staged files are actually the old code (pre-commmit), and to make my newly pushed code visible, I need to git stash everything.  What I'm trying to accomplish is that when code is pushed from Local to Bare, it is automatically available for viewing on the Development server, and requires no manipulation of Development directly.

An example -- On Local:

Change autoload.php on the 'dev' branch to use new php 5.4 arrays

```
$autoload = []; // instead of $autoload = array();
```

Push to my Bare repo

```
git push
```

Post-receive fires correctly and moves the code from the 'dev' branch on Bare to the 'dev' branch on Development.

Now if I perform a git status on Development, I have:

```
modified:  application/config/autoload.php
```

autoload.php still shows the old code:

```
$autoload = array();
```

It is only after I perform git stash that my new code becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be pushing to a non-bare branch. That is what is causing things to get out of sync in this way. When you git stash it has the effect of syncing files back to HEAD, which now includes your changes.

It would be better for to connect to the Development server and have it do a git pull.

Comment: Except with a bare repo on my development server, visiting that location in the browser just gives me the directory structure of the git repo.  However, I will give the post-receive performing an ssh and git pull a try.

Comment: They are both bare repos? So only the git files are on you dev server?